# PL/SQL hierarchical ordering

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I've got a table which contains three columns.
The table contains values as "ID, NAME, ADMIN".

Example Table

```
ID      NAME       ADMIN
200      A          1
300      B          2
400      C          3
500      D          1
600      E          3
```

Now I want to get them into a text area ordered by "ADMIN".
In the text area they should be listed like

```
A
D
  B
    C
    E
```

I've tried something like this, but didn't worked.

```
SELECT a.id, REPLACE (LPAD (' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 4, ' '), ' ', '&nbsp;') || a.name
FROM (SELECT   *
      FROM my_table a
      ORDER BY a.name, a.admin)
CONNECT BY a.admin > PRIOR a.admin
START WITH a.admin IS NULL
```

Comment: What did you get by using your script? SELECT looks fine. But you don't have `ADMIN IS NULL` in your example table

Comment: I didn't get any result back, no error but either no data.

Comment: Likely it is because you don't have `ADMIN IS NULL` in your example table. It is no root in your example

Comment: Why not simple query: `select lpad('&nbsp;', (admin-1)*4, '&nbsp;')||name from my_table order by admin, id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have the **LEVEL** stored in the table as **ADMIN**, you do not need the **CONNECT BY** clause. You just need to format your output using **LPAD**.

For example,

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(1), ADMIN NUMBER);

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (ID, NAME, ADMIN)
         VALUES (200, 'A', 1)
    INTO t (ID, NAME, ADMIN)
         VALUES (300, 'B', 2)
    INTO t (ID, NAME, ADMIN)
         VALUES (400, 'C', 3)
    INTO t (ID, NAME, ADMIN)
         VALUES (500, 'D', 1)
    INTO t (ID, NAME, ADMIN)
         VALUES (600, 'E', 3)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT lpad(' ',2*(ADMIN-1)) || NAME name_hierarchy FROM t ORDER BY ADMIN, NAME;

NAME_HIERARCHY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A
D
  B
    C
    E
```